# Is z Re(z) differentiable at origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was solving it while doing cr equations problem but it turns out to be differentiable whereas question says vice versa

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just apply the definition: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {f(z)-f(0)} z=\lim_{z \to 0} Re (z)=0$ so the function is differentiable at the origin and the value of the derivative is $0$.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Only the title is clear and I took the title as the correct question.

Comment: It's what have I done but it's differentiable but question says vice versa

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually it was asking to show that the function is not differentiable at origin though continuous everywhere

Comment: Continuity was solved but not differentiability at origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question says $f$ is not differentiable at the origin then it is wrong

C-R equation are irrelevant for this question. Just apply the definition: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {f(z)-f(0)} z=\lim_{z \to 0} Re (z)=0$ so the function is differentiable at the origin and the value of the derivative is $0$.

Comment: Exactly,but question says it's not differentiable

Comment: I don't know why?

Comment: You are right and the question  is wrong. The function is surely differentiable at the origin. @ShubhankarSarkar

Comment: I was thinking similarly and hope it to be wrong. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=zx=x^2+ixy=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

$u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ together hold   at the point $(0,0)$ only and not in any open neighborhood of it. Hence $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$ but not analytic.

Comment: C-R equation are irrelevant for this question. Just apply the definition: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {f(z)-f(0)} z=\lim_{z \to 0} Re (z)=0$ so the function is differentiable at the origin and the value of the derivative is $0$.

Comment: What about this procedure? We can't believe cr equations to be perfect for determining differentiability of a function because it is failed on many occurrences

Comment: I wouldn't say "irrelevant": they at least give some hope for the function to be differentiable at zero, as it actually is. They though do not provide the whole answer.

Comment: CR-equations are the consequence of differentiability. If they are satisfied in open neighborhood of some point then  $f$ is analytic, if satisfied on a curve $y=g(x)$ or  a point $z=a$ then $f$ is differentiable on them respectively.